# migrate existing biztalk server database from sql server 2008 R2 to sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, biztalk

we are planning to move biztalk database from one place to another as well as upgrade the sql server.
the initial database is in sql server 2008 R2 and target is sql server 2012.
but the thing is that we have to set up database on another system,
i tried to search it on msdn but they are providing reference to upgrade from 2005 to 2008 , or moving database from one server to another.
do you think that will work in my case !!
i found this article.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378547%28v=bts.10%29.aspx
relating to upgrading as well as moving..
but this is quite older one.
how can i upgrade as well as move biztalk database from sql server 2008 R2 to sql server 2012 on a different system (side by side upgrade).

do i have to follow same steps as upgrading a normal database from sql server 2008R2 to sql server 2012 or some other one ??

Comment: This question is about server administration so it belongs on [SF].

Comment: Very important, you do not mention upgrading you BizTalk Server version.  You must do that as well.

Comment: actually we are upgrading biztalk server as well, the initial is biztalk server 2006 and target is server 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the SQL Server edition (2012 in your case) you are migrating to is supported by your BizTalk Server edition, you can follow the procedure to [move BizTalk databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378546.aspx).
You can check the version compatibility [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926628).

Comment: i did found backup job, but the restore instructions are given for 2008 !! will they work for 2012 ?

Comment: As the content in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546753(v=bts.80).aspx) applies to BizTalk 2013 and 2013 R2 (noted in the intro), you should be good to use this.

Comment: i was asking whether these restore step will work in sql 2012, as there it is showing sql server 2008 R2

Comment: I'm aware that the article states SQL 2008 R2 but I don't see any reason why these steps should be any different with SQL 2012.

Comment: The steps are identical, but you cannot run BizTalk Server 2009 or BizTalk Server 2010 with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: actually it's a 24x7x365 running server so i need to be full sure before i can finalize the steps.

Comment: U should always test these migrate/upgrade procedures in your Test/Staging environment before going to your Production environment.

Comment: yp but my lead asked me the same question i asked you that whether these steps will work in case of sql server 2012 and your answers were quite helpful.